# Find the speed and surface area of parametric equation

Tags: calculus, integration, area, parametric

> Consider the parametric curve
>   $$x=5+\cos(t)$$
>   $$y = 1 + \sin(t)$$
>
> (1) Find the speed of a particle whose position is given by this parametric curve.
>
> (2) Rotate the parametric curve about the $y$ - axis. Find the surface area  A  of the surface obtained.

Here is my work on this problem:

**Solving (1)**

The speed of a particle is given by:

$$\frac{ds}{dt}= \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2}$$

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\sin(t)$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=\cos(t)$

$\frac{ds}{dt} = \sqrt{(-\sin(t))^2+(\cos(t))^2} = \sqrt{\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)} = 1$

The speed is, $\frac{ds}{dt}=1$

**Solving (2)**

The differential area for rotating about the $y$ - axis is given by the equation:

$$dA = 2 \pi x \sqrt{f'(t)^2+g'(t)^2}dt$$

$f(t) = x = 5 + \cos(t)$

$f'(t) = -\sin(t)$

$g(t) = y = 1 + \sin(t)$

$g'(t) = \cos(t)$

$dA = 2 \pi (5 + \cos(t)) \sqrt{(-\sin(t))^2+(\cos(t))^2}dt$

$dA = 2 \pi (5 + \cos(t))dt$

$A = \int (10\pi + 2\pi\cos(t))dt$

$A = \int (10\pi + 2\pi\cos(t))dt$

$A = 10\pi t + 2\pi\sin(t) + C$

Could you point out where I have gone wrong?

Comment: You need bounds for integration

Comment: @OsamaGhani No bounds are given. All the information I wrote in the post is the given. That's why I included the +C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (2),  note that the surface area is the same for the curve 
$$ x =5+\cos\theta , \>\>\>\>\>y = \sin\theta, \>\>\>\>\> t\in[0,2 \pi]$$

The area integral is

\begin{align}
A & = 2\int_0^6 2\pi x \sqrt{1+ (y’_x)^2}dx\\
&= 4\pi\int_\pi^0 (5+\cos\theta)\sqrt{1+\cot^2\theta}(-\sin\theta)d\theta \\
&= 4\pi\int^\pi_0 (5+\cos\theta)d\theta = 20\pi^2\\
\end{align}

Comment: How did you came up with the limits of integration if it is not stated in the problem? :o

Comment: @Diego note that the given curve is periodic with the period $2\pi$. So, it is enough to consider the limit $[0,2\pi]$